# How to toggle between three differens menus and keep last chosen menu open despite loading new page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I know basically nothing about javascipt, jquery, php...unfortunately I only know html and css. But I am starting school to learn this autumn! The problem is I am really struggling with a page that I need to make for a client now. And time is so short.

I need three different menus, and for it to be possible to toggle between them and not change on loading a new page. I have made a mockup of it, where the only things clickable is the three tabs on top, and the menu link "tjenester" on all three menus:

https://xd.adobe.com/view/d65891b7-9514-4640-4da6-47c4ebd6b8f6-a069/

Is there any way I can achieve the possibility to toggle between those three tabs, with their associated menu, and keep that open even when another page is clicked and opened?

As i said I am a noobie...and I need to make this site in Wordpress, with the Avada theme. I initially thought I could solve this by linking each of the tabs to different pages, with their own custom menu - which is easy in Avada. But found that this of course is horrible SEO.. I can't have three "home" pages, three "about" pages etc. I need the header to change and stay as last selected, despite page load. The Avada theme is installed and initial setup is at https://yourcustomizer.com. All help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to persist a state across page loads using only HTML and CSS. A fairly simple JavaScript solution might be to apply a class to the body based on a setting in local storage. Then you'd have to set the latest class in local storage each time it changes.

Something like:

```
<script>
    function setMenu(menu) {
       localStorage.setItem("currentMenu", menu);
    }
    function getMenu() {
        var currentMenu = localStorage.getItem("currentMenu");
        if (currentMenu) {
            document.body.setAttribute("class", currentMenu);
        }
    }
    document.body.addEventListener("load", getMenu());
    var thingThatChangesTheMenu = document.getElementById("thingID");
</script>
```

```
<html>
    <body>
        [...]
        <button onclick="setMenu('menu1')">menu 1</button>
        <button onclick="setMenu('menu2')">menu 2</button>
        <button onclick="setMenu('menu3')">menu 3</button>
        [...]
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<style>
.menu1Container {
     display: none;
}
.menu2Container {
    display: none;
}
.menu3Container {
    display: none;
}
body.menu1 .menu1Container {
    display: block;
}
body.menu2 .menu2Container {
    display: block;
}
body.menu3 .menu3Container {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

This is a simplified version that assumes you don't have any other classes on the body that you care about. Hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I am not nearly experienced enough to understand where to put these codes :( I'm really a noobie and haven't tried using any other code than editing existing Wordpress css, html and basic php :-/ Is there any way I can implement this with the existing wordpress menu "framework" - so that I can make the three menus as I normally would in Wordpress admin, and load them by adding classes to them, instead of writing them all in code?

Comment: Another option could perhaps be that I make a menu with the three menu items, each with a dropdown menu displayed horizontally, and somehow make it so that the chosen dropdown is always visible, and will stay visible despite loading new pages.. Like an accordion drop down, just horizontal (I feel retarded)